# How to do a for loop with case_when

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, case

I'm a beginner with R and I'm trying to do a for-loop to recode many variables: when "test" modality is missing, then have "test.v1" modality. It looked very easy to do, but I can't get it:

```
VEC_1 <- c("test1","test2","test3","test4","test5","test6","test7","test8","test9")
VEC_2 <- c("test1.v1","test2.v1","test3.v1","test4.v1","test5.v1","test6.v1","test7.v1","test8.v1","test9.v1") 
 
for (i in 1:(min(length(VEC_1), length(VEC_2)))){
    df2 <- df1 %>%
        mutate(
          VEC_1[i] = case_when(
          is.na(VEC_1[i]) & !is.na(VEC_2[i]) ~ VEC_2[i],
          TRUE ~ VEC_1[i])
    )
}
```

I have this error

```
Unexpected error : '=' in:
"    mutate(
      VEC_1[i] ="
```

Does anyone have an idea ?

**EDIT:** df1 is like :

```
test1 <- c("A","B","A","A",NA,"B","A",NA,"A")
test1.v1 <- c("B",NA,"B","B","A","B","B",NA,"A") 
test2 <- c("B","B","B","B",NA,"C","C","C","C")
test2.v1 <- c("C",NA,"A","A","B","B","C",NA,"C") 
test3 <- c("A","B","B","B",NA,"C","C",NA,"C")
test3.v1 <- c("B","A","B",NA,"A","A","A","A",NA) 
test4 <- c(NA,"B","B","A",NA,"B","A",NA,"A")
test4.v1 <- c("B","B","B","A","A","B","B","B","B") 

df1 <- data.frame(test1,test1.v1,test2,test2.v1,test3,test3.v1,test4,test4.v1)
```

Comment: `df1` is undefined in your code.  Your loop overwrites `df2` at every iteration.  Why?  You have no `NA`s in your test data.  This sort of operation can be done in R without the need for a `for` loop.  Is there a particular reason for wanting to use one here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the example data.frame `df1`, I'm wondering if you might try putting your data into long form, then grouping by row number and test, then substituting missing values.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c("test", "mode"), names_pattern = "test(\\d+)([.v1]*)") %>%
  group_by(rn, test) %>%
  mutate(value = ifelse(mode == "" & is.na(value), value[mode == ".v1"], value)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = rn, names_from = c(test, mode), values_from = value, names_prefix = "test", names_sep = "")
```

**Output**

```
     rn test1 test1.v1 test2 test2.v1 test3 test3.v1 test4 test4.v1
  <int> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr>   
1     1 A     B        B     C        A     B        B     B       
2     2 B     NA       B     NA       B     A        B     B       
3     3 A     B        B     A        B     B        B     B       
4     4 A     B        B     A        B     NA       A     A       
5     5 A     A        B     B        A     A        A     A       
6     6 B     B        C     B        C     A        B     B       
7     7 A     B        C     C        C     A        A     B       
8     8 NA    NA       C     NA       A     A        B     B       
9     9 A     A        C     C        C     NA       A     B
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `VEC_1` and `VEC_2` are the same length here. you don't need to use a for-loop, `mutate` affects the whole column of the dataframe, it kinda behaves like a for-loop. I have rewritten your code like this and changed the data for testing purposes:

```
library(dplyr)

VEC_1 <- c("test1","test2","test3","test4",NA,"test6","test7",NA,"test9")
VEC_2 <- c("test1.v1",NA,"test3.v1","test4.v1","test5.v1","test6.v1","test7.v1",NA,"test9.v1") 

df <- data.frame(VEC_1,VEC_2)

df %>% mutate(VEC_1 = if_else(is.na(VEC_1) & !is.na(VEC_2),VEC_2,VEC_1))
```

which is equal to

```
df <- data.frame(VEC_1,VEC_2)

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(is.na(df$VEC_1[i]) & !is.na(df$VEC_2[i])){
    df$VEC_1[i] = df$VEC_2[i]
  }
}
```

Output:

```
> df
     VEC_1    VEC_2
1    test1 test1.v1
2    test2     <NA>
3    test3 test3.v1
4    test4 test4.v1
5 test5.v1 test5.v1
6    test6 test6.v1
7    test7 test7.v1
8     <NA>     <NA>
9    test9 test9.v1
```

i also changed from case_when to if_else, because you only check one condition.

```
?if_else
if_else(condition, true, false, missing = NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ifelse`/`if_else` will be a good solution, unless you have multiple conditions, then `case_when` is your friend.  A loop isn't necessary:

```
library(dplyr)

VEC_1 <- c("test1","test2",NA,NA)
VEC_2 <- c("test1.v1",NA,NA,"test4.v1") 

df <- tibble(VEC_1, VEC_2)    

df %>% 
  mutate(VEC_1 = case_when(
    is.na(VEC_2) ~ VEC_1,
    is.na(VEC_1) ~ VEC_2, 
    TRUE ~ VEC_1)
  )

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  VEC_1 VEC_2   
  <chr> <chr>   
1 test1 test1.v1
2 test2 NA      
3 NA    NA      
4 NA    test4.v1

# A tibble: 4 × 2
  VEC_1    VEC_2   
  <chr>    <chr>   
1 test1    test1.v1
2 test2    NA      
3 NA       NA      
4 test4.v1 test4.v1
```

Comment: thanks, but I wasn't clear (I edited my question), these are columns in vectors